# how to get Hudson CI to include test results in the status email

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I've been evaluating Hudson, with an eye to convert to it from CC.NET.  In CC.NET, I've gotten my emails to include test statistics, such as # of tests run, how many failed, etc.  It even shows in red "this project has no tests" which is a great motivator, right?

Is there any way to accomplish this in Hudson?

I've tried the email-ext plugin, because I'm told that it can get test output and other great stuff into the email, but I just can't figure out "how."

It looks like I need to put a token in for "content" but I dont see any token available that looks like "test results" to me :)  Or any that would parse some xml that I provide a path to, or such.

Has anyone done this and can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) wiki page:

> To see a list of all available email tokens and what they display, you can click the "?" (question mark) at the top of the email-ext section on the project configuration screen.

I can't check if it's listed in the online help right now but I think you're looking for the `$FAILED_TESTS` token.

If you need more guidance, check this blog post: [Continuous Integration with Hudson, ColdFusion, and MXUnit: Advanced Notification Control](http://blog.mxunit.org/2009/08/continuous-integration-with-hudson_29.html). There are some screenshots that might help.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I see that list of tokens, but unless there are failing tests, I just dont see a token that provides the information I'm asking about.  The number of tests run, even if they all passed, and most importantly - the fact that a given project doesnt even have any tests.

Answer (score 1):

See this question - [Having Latest Tests Results info in the notified email with Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845020/having-latest-tests-results-info-in-the-notified-email-with-hudson) . It seems like the only answer is to hack in your own solution, until Email-ext is improved.