# Having Latest Tests Results info in the notified email with Hudson

Tags: java, email, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a project with a lot of tests failing, so it would be great for me to receive by email the number of failed tests compare from the latest build.
What i need is just the info that appears in the project's page by the test results link:

Latest Test Result (10 failures / -2)

Is this possible? I've already tried the email-ext plugin, but it is not telling me that info (I can have the list of failing tests with output etc., but I really just need that info above).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I used a patch for the email-ext plugin, that allows you to have a groovy template for your email. I think this should be integrated in the main plugin btw.

This is the page I read:

http://techkriti.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/using-groovy-with-hudson-to-send-rich-text-email/

hopefully it'll be useful for somebody else

roberto

Answer (score -1):

Why not compile the results yourself? When your trying to fix bugs quickly, writing another program at the same time seems counter intuitive.

Comment: Um, what? Who said anything about writing another program?